# Issue in calling Webservice using URLConnection

Tags: java, url, url-encoding

I have a url as following

```
String url = "http://host.com/connect/v1.3/serviceProducts?q=\"lookupName\" LIKE 'A9051%'"
```

This url points to a restful webservice. Whenever I try to hitting this url using `HttpURLConnection` but it always returns be **`301 Moved Permanently`** response.

I have tried encoding the url. But still it failed to work. Below is the code of my attempt to encode it.

```
try {
    url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DbInteraction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
url = url.replace("%3A", ":").replace("%2F", "/").replace("%3F", "?").replace("%3D", "=").replace("%25", "%");
```

After the encoding my url looks like this.

```
http://host.com/connect/v1.3/serviceProducts?q=%22lookupName%22+LIKE+%27A9051%%27
```

With this encoded url as well I'm still getting `301 Status`. 
I also tried with the below url format

```
http://host.com/connect/v1.3/serviceProducts?q=%22lookupName%22%20LIKE%20%27A9051%%27
```

I don't understand where am I going wrong. Please suggest.

I've tried testing the service in Postman and it works as expected there.

PS: This is a dummy url with modified host details.

**UPDATE:**

Here are some more ways I tried hitting the url:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fhost.com%2Fconnect%2Fv1.3%2FserviceProducts%3Fq%3D%22lookupName%22LIKE%27A9051%25%27

http://host.com/connect/v1.3/serviceProducts%3Fq%3D%22lookupName%22+LIKE+%27A9051%25%27

http://host.com/connect/v1.3/serviceProducts?q%3D%22lookupName%22+LIKE+%27A9051%25%27

http://host.com/connect/v1.3/serviceProducts?q=%22lookupName%22+LIKE+%27A9051%25%27
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do any replacements after you did `URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");` because this is actually the encoded string that you need to use.

Comment: With this encoding, it was converting even all the slashes to some hex code.. This is how the url looked like.. `http%3A%2F%2Fhost.com%2Fconnect%2Fv1.3%2FserviceProducts%3Fq%3D%22lookupName%22LIKE%27A9051%25%27` . Anyways I tried hitting the service this way as well.. But didnt get the desired response

Comment: Because the response is `301` you should check the `Location` header returned in the response and make request to this one you will find there.  
It is what a browser does for you when you try it.  
For more details check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Comment: @HarshitaSethi any updates based on my previous comment? Did you try it?

Comment: The Location mentioned is similar to the encoded URL `http://host.com/connect/v1.3/serviceProducts?q=%22lookupName%22%20LIKE%20%27A9051%%27`. This is not working when I'm calling the service through URLConnection. But the ooriginal service works on Postman. So I think it is correct and should give some result.